# Make Openlayers center & bounds context aware

Tags: javascript, location

I'm creating geospatial database for multiple municipalities. Each should be able to work in it's own context (not only see only own data, **but also have custom center & bounds for input and output maps**).

I tried to find this functionality in OpenLayers module, but wasn't successful. I only found "zoom to layer" functionality, which isn't applicable, because there will be different layers for each municipality.

The most straightforward way I can think of is using geofield-defined bounds in user entity, which OpenLayers could use.

Do you know about any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The key is adapting https://drupal.org/node/904898 by switching Geo Taxonomy to Geofield or Postgis for Drupal 7.